# Visual Studio 2015 generate UML from code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uml, class-diagram

- Windows 10 64-bit
- Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Version:14.0.25431.01 Update 3

I have a almost finished project and now I need to write a documentation. I found some information in the www which tells to "simply" generate UML from the existing code.

At the top Menu is a section with **Architecture** and there I can create *new* UML diagrams, but I can't import the classes which the project have. In all the other forum entries they was talking about a **Architecture Explorer** where you can simply drag and drop the needed classes and the dependencies are automatically created, but in my case this view is missing.

If you have some good advise how to document the software differently, you're welcome.

Comment: I don't know your environment, but "just create UML" is not going to be a documentation. At best you get some graphics. You need to make a model from the scaffold you might get. This model can be basis of a documentation.

Comment: @ThomasKilian yes I know. But my part of the project is to deliver the one side the implementation and on the other the fitting diagrams.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In solution explorer right click and:

add > item.. > General > class diagram

Then you can fairly easy make a domain model by dragging entity classes in and right click on a few properties and choose: "Show as association"

Comment: Now I have all needed classes there., but dont find "Show as association".

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @amod0017 Keep in mind that if we talk about _association_, it not goes around which object is used in which class, but which class inherits from which interface/class. At this point I also thought the class diagram is like we learned in university with the first _association_ I explained above, but it isn't.

Comment: So, how do you add associations within Visual Studio? I have an MVC project.

Comment: @naz786 nowadays I use ReSharper to generate a dependency diagram.

Answer (score 9):

To view UML diagram of your project, make right-click on your project and select View->Class diagram. Auto-generated UML of your project will be opened

Comment: This worked, but now I only have the class diagrams without the dependencies, how can I add them?